# Function to create df with multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: function, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a new df from another df using groupby as below:

```
weekly_by_user = \
df.groupby('week','user_id') \
.agg( \
    count('order_id').alias('total_orders'), \
    sum('gmv').alias('gmv'), \
    countDistinct('buyer_id').alias('dcnt_buyers'))
```

My expectation is to create a function that can pass in all 3 columns (order_id, gmv, buyer_id) and 3 functions (count, sum, countDistinct), and return the same output as query above.

For the case of 1 col, it can by done by create a function:

```
def df_new(df, cols, func, new_col_name):
    for col in cols:
        df_new = df.groupby('week','user_id') \
    .agg(func(col).alias(new_col_name))
    return df_new
```

and then run for the first col like:

```
total_orders = df_groupby(df, 'order_id', count, 'total_orders')
```

But I don't know how to apply for all 3 cols in 1 function. Can anyone suggest the solution?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def df_new(df, cols, funcs, new_col_names):
  df_new = (
    df
    .groupby('week', 'user_id')
    .agg(*[func(cols[index]).alias(new_col_names[index]) for index, func in enumerate(funcs)])
  )

  return df_new
```